# Conflict for FMDB acting as submodule in two projects cascaded together

Tags: xcode, git, fmdb, git-submodules

Description:
Integrating FMDB in XCode 4.5 for iOS project.
a> Proj A and proj B, B is a submodule in A.
b> FMDB is the submodule for both A and B.

Problem:
Conflict! 
a> If the FMDB in B is removed, then having error of missing files
b> If keeping both FMDB or using the FMDB in A for B, then having error of duplicated files

Any one has idea on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the classes in one of the FMDB projects, giving it a new prefix.  I've had to do this a couple of times myself.